# How do I separate two different creation/ann operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, oscillators

$a$ and $b$ are identical systems. The Hamiltonian is given by $H=H_a+H_b =a^\dagger_k a_k +b^\dagger_k b_k$ and these are non-interacting particles.

How do I separate a time dependent operator
$A(t)= e^{(iH_0t)}Ae^{(-iH_0t)}$
with $A=a^\dagger_k b_{k'}$ into a form that I can write $e^{(iH_at)}a_ke^{(-iH_at)}$ and $e^{(iH_bt)}b_{k'}e^{(-iH_bt)}.$

Comment: Hint: $[H_a,H_b]=0$, so $e^{iHt} a_k^\dagger e^{-iHt}= e^{iH_a t} a_k^\dagger e^{-iH_at} $...

Comment: So a und b commute to their Hamiltonian system. Does this mean that the time dependent operator is $A(t)= e^{(iH_at)}a^\dagger_k e^{(-iH_at)}e^{(iH_bt)}b_ke^{(-iH_bt)}$?

Comment: Yes, it is clear now, thank you. If I derive the $\frac{dA(t)}{dt}= i[H_a,a^\dagger_k(t)]b_k(t)+ia^\dagger_k(t)[H_b,b_k(t)] = 0$ as $ a^\dagger_k(t)=e^{(iH_at)}a^\dagger_k e^{(-iH_at)}$ and $b_k=e^{(iH_bt)}b_ke^{(-iH_bt)}$ I get the expectation value of this System. If a individual chemical potential would be added to the the Hamiltonian($H=\mu_aH_a+\mu_bH_b$) than $\frac{dA(t)}{dt}= i\mu_a([H_a,a^\dagger_k(t)]b_k(t))+i\mu_b(a^\dagger_k(t)[H_b,b_k(t)]) \neq 0$.